Excel number of combinations inside a specific array
Think of this problem similar to a lottery:
I have been trying to determine all possible combinations of 15 numbers (from 1 to 25). By mathematical calculation, I know it is 3.268.760 possibilities.
So, if I played a simple ticket of 15 numbers in the lottery (numbers from 1 to 25), my probability to win would be 3.268.760. The draw is 15 numbers.
Now, I am not sure how to calculate the same probability if I start giving conditions. For example:
What is the number of possibilities (and which are they) if I set the condition: 8 odd numbers and 7 even numbers?
Ideally, I need vba to list all the 8 odd numbers and 7 pair numbers combinations from 1 till 25, however, I know this will be over 10 thousand possibilities.
So, what if instead of numbers 1 till 25, I narrowed, say, 20 numbers? would it be possible to randomize the 20 numbers and give me all possible games (15 numbers) which would be 8 odd and 7 even numbers?
This is an example of 5 games which meets my criteria (8 odd and 7 even numbers)

This is the "skimmed" example of numbers I need to find all 8 odd and 7 pair combinations and the results:

Maybe VBA is not the tool for that, maybe Python...any thoughts?
*Important: The position of the numbers does not matter (number 1 can be in column 1,A or in column 15,O)

Think this has been asked a couple of times of late.  Have a search though this site.

I believe problems like this will be much easier to handle in Python than in Excel, for what it's worth. You will probably find it convenient to work with multiple-precision integers as much as possible -- postpone floating point numbers as long as possible. I think there might be decimal arithmetic class that is relevant.

FYI since in a lottery order is significant, you want to calculate permutations (order matters) and not combinations (where order doesn't matter).  The number of permutations for selecting 15 items from 25 items is about 4.3 x 10^18

Re combination vs permutation, here in the U.S. lotteries nearly always order the picked numbers and you can't usually pick the same number twice. So for instance if you picked four number 13, 8, 11, 6 .... this is really picking 6, 8, 11, 13

this code worked:
Sub GenerateCombinations()
Dim nums As Variant
Dim odds As Variant
Dim evens As Variant
Dim oddComb As Variant
Dim evenComb As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim resultWs As Worksheet
Dim oddCounter As Long
Dim evenCounter As Long
Dim combinationCounter As Long
' Read numbers from the sheet
nums = Range("A1:A18").Value

' Separate odd and even numbers
ReDim odds(1 To 10)
ReDim evens(1 To 8)
oddCounter = 1
evenCounter = 1

For i = 1 To UBound(nums)
    If nums(i, 1) Mod 2 = 0 Then
        evens(evenCounter) = nums(i, 1)
        evenCounter = evenCounter + 1
    Else
        odds(oddCounter) = nums(i, 1)
        oddCounter = oddCounter + 1
    End If
Next i

' Generate combinations
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Numbers")
Set resultWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
resultWs.Name = "Combinations"
combinationCounter = 1

For i = 1 To UBound(odds) - 7
    For j = i + 1 To UBound(odds) - 6
        For k = j + 1 To UBound(odds) - 5
            For l = k + 1 To UBound(odds) - 4
                For m = l + 1 To UBound(odds) - 3
                    For n = m + 1 To UBound(odds) - 2
                        For o = n + 1 To UBound(odds) - 1
                            For p = o + 1 To UBound(odds)
                                For q = 1 To UBound(evens) - 6
                                    For r = q + 1 To UBound(evens) - 5
                                        For s = r + 1 To UBound(evens) - 4
                                            For t = s + 1 To UBound(evens) - 3
                                                For u = t + 1 To UBound(evens) - 2
                                                    For v = u + 1 To UBound(evens) - 1
                                                        For w = v + 1 To UBound(evens)
                                                            resultWs.Cells(combinationCounter, 1).Value = odds(i)
                                                            resultWs.Cells(combinationCounter, 2).Value = odds(j)
                                                            resultWs.Cells(combinationCounter, 3).Value = odds(k)
                                                            resultWs.Cells(combinationCounter, 4).Value = odds(l)
                                                            resultWs.Cells(combinationCounter, 5).Value = odds(m)
                                                            resultWs.Cells(combinationCounter, 6).Value = odds(n)
                                                            resultWs.Cells(combinationCounter, 7).Value = odds(o)
                                                            resultWs.Cells(combinationCounter, 8).Value = odds(p)
                                                            resultWs.Cells(combinationCounter, 9).Value = evens(q)
                                                            resultWs.Cells(combinationCounter, 10).Value = evens(r)
                                                            resultWs.Cells(combinationCounter, 11).Value = evens(s)
                                                            resultWs.Cells(combinationCounter, 12).Value = evens(t)
                                                            resultWs.Cells(combinationCounter, 13).Value = evens(u)
                                                            resultWs.Cells(combinationCounter, 14).Value = evens(v)
                                                            resultWs.Cells(combinationCounter, 15).Value = evens(w)
                                                            combinationCounter = combinationCounter + 1
                                                        Next w
                                                    Next v
                                                Next u
                                            Next t
                                        Next s
                                    Next r
                                Next q
                            Next p
                        Next o
                    Next n
                Next m
            Next l
        Next k
    Next j
Next i

MsgBox "Combinations generated successfully!"

End Sub
